# Mapbox + JavaScript (Remove layer)

Tags: javascript, mapbox, jquery

The attached script was created for the geojson file I created that works properly.

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
      $(pz).click(function() {
        L.mapbox.featureLayer('map.geojson').addTo(map)
    })
    });
</script>
```

My question is how can I hide the displayed layer with the click feature?

I would like to ask you some help to create the script.

(I use mapbox.js not mapbox-gl.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an official Mapbox examples which shows how to toggle layers using `onclick`:

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/layers/

Comment: Thank you, I try this example, but it does not work for something. The displayable layer can be retrieved from a dropdown / semantic menu ... it may be the problem ...

Answer (score 1):

My JavaScript is not that good, but instead of `click` look at https://api.jquery.com/toggle/

and then `map.remove();` if needed depending on how `$.toggle` works.

PS: jquery could be added to your tags